# PHP: is there difference between Index, Element, Key, Value of an Array?... are they the same thing?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key, element

When dealing with `PHP` `array`s, I quite often here terms such as:

`Array` `Key`,

`Array` `Index`,

`Array` `Element`,

`Array` `Value`

Can someone, **PLEASE** , in **simple** terms explain what each of these *basically* means?

Is there any difference?... are they all referring to the same thing?

Where do you use which? and when?

Any clarification with some simple *use case* examples will be highly appreciated.

i.e: in an array like: `array($a,$b,$c,$d=>$e)` What will be What?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array is a collection of Elements.
Every element has key & value. Key can be a integer(index) or a string.
In you case

`array($a, $b, $c, $d=>$e)`

can be rewritten as

```
array(0 => $a, 1 => $b, 2 => $c, $d => $e);
```

Where 0, 1, 2, $d are the keys of the array.
You can refer 0, 1, 2 as a  index for value $a,$b,$c respectively and $d is a key for $e.

.

Comment: What do you mean by `value.Key`?

Comment: So, should i want to check if `$a` or `$b` or `$c` exists or are put there what `function` should used is there any `function` in `PHP` to check if an `Index` exists or is available?

Comment: Thanks again. I check the site but there is not example with an `index` `array`. All examples have `key=>value` setup. how do you implement the same in a basic `index` `array` like `array($a,$b,$c)` ?

Comment: array_key_exists("0",array($a,$b,$c)),array_key_exists("1",array($a,$b,$c)),array_key_exists("2",array($a,$b,$c)) or  you can use isset

Comment: Managed to go through... **Yes it worked** and Thank you very much for the explanation. Am accepting your answer

Answer (score 1):

Key == Index, Element == Value

Comment: can u please Explain?... in an array like: `array($a,$b,$c,$d=>$e)` What will be What?

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
array(
    0  => $a, // index: 0, value : $a
    1  => $b, // index: 1, value : $b
    2  => $c, // index: 2, value : $c
    $d => $e  // index: $d, value : $e
)
```

Comment: What about the `Element` and the `Key`?... Why is there only `index` and `value`?... [I am really is confused].

Comment: As @enumag has already told you, "key" is analog to "index" and "element" is analog to "value". ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience most PHP documentation uses the key => value configuration, while index: element is more common in JavaScript and jQuery.

**PHP docs:**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**JavaScript Docs (Mozilla):**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

They both apply to the same concept where objects in an array have an index or key, and subsidiary objects, elements or values attached to that key.